# What are the differences in the MVC pattern on the web vs desktop?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, desktop

After doing some reading on the Model View Controller pattern it seems that the pattern is implemented quite differently in web frameworks vs desktop frameworks. With web based MVC frameworks the view and model never communicate directly. They can only communicate with the controller. But in desktop implementations, it seems that the view and model can communicate directly which doesn't make sense to me. That would seem to defeat the purpose of MVC of having separate, clean, isolated layers. Plus, what does the controller do if the view and model communicate directly?

Here is a diagram from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller) illustrating MVC.

[image]

[Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this article that seems to best explain the issue. http://andrzejonsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/09/rails-is-not-mvc.html

It appears that there are really two architectures going by the same name: MVC and Model2.

Answer (score 0):

It's a funny thing that I wrote recently an article on my blog about the different implementation of the MVC concept in web frameworks.

You can read it [here](http://activedeveloper.info/mvc-is-a-lie).

Answer (score 0):

also there is [Presentation-abstraction-control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation-abstraction-control)